# Load list item to dispaly get_fieldValues?

Tags: list, javascript, sharepoint-online, jquery, list-item

I'm using SharePoint online and have a SharePoint-hosted app.

I have a page with a question form that send data in to Sharepoint using `listItem.set_item('GEN_1_blabla', $('#GEN_1').val());`

Now in my list when you click on an item it's open in DispForm.aspx and in there i have my question page again how can i get it to load the information to the textboxes in my question page.

I have read about `get_fieldValues()` but dont know how to get it to work.

```
var appContext, hostweburl, hostContext, parentWeb, list;

appContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
hostweburl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl"));
hostContext = new SP.AppContextSite(appContext, hostweburl);
parentWeb = hostContext.get_web();
list = parentWeb.get_lists().getByTitle("CoromaticIFU");

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#tabs").tabs();
    $(document).tooltip();
    $('#GEN_4').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' }).val();
    $('#save').click(setItems);
});

function setItems() {
   var listCreationInformation = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation(), listItem = list.addItem(listCreationInformation);

    listItem.set_item('GEN_1_Sum_Scope_Assigment', $('#GEN_1').val());
    listItem.set_item('GEN_1_Sum_Scope_Assigment_D', $('#GEN_1_D').val());
    listItem.set_item('GEN_2_CRMname', $('#GEN_2').val());
    listItem.set_item('GEN_2_CRMname_D', $('#GEN_2_D').val());
    (etc)
    listItem.set_item('GEN_19_BYGG_GOLV', $('input[name="GEN19"]:checked').val());
    (etc)
    listItem.set_item('DRI_6_Personnel_Servicetype', $("#DRI_6 option:selected").text());
    (etc)
    listItem.update();

    appContext.load(listItem);
    appContext.executeQueryAsync(function (success) { alert("Din sparning lyckades!"); }, function (sender, args) { alert('Error:' + args.get_message()); });
}
```

I have tried this with `get_fieldValues`

```
function getItems()
{
    listItem.get_fieldValues('GEN_1_Sum_Scope_Assigment', $('#GEN_1').val());
    listItem.update();

    appContext.load(listitem);
    appContext.executeQueryAsync(function (success) { alert("lyckades!"); }, function (sender, args) { alert('Error:' + args.get_message()); });

}
```

Comment: listItem.get_fieldValues() returns the JSON containing the item values as {internalname1:value1,internalname2:value2,....}

Comment: ok how can i write the code to get to work?

Answer (score 1):

Answer:

```
var item = list.getItemById(92);

$(document).ready(function () {

appContext.load(item);
appContext.executeQueryAsync(function () {
   $('#GEN_1').val(item.get_fieldValues().GEN_1_Sum_Scope_Assigment);
    $('#GEN_1_D').val(item.get_fieldValues().GEN_1_Sum_Scope_Assigment_D);
    $('#GEN_2').val(item.get_fieldValues().GEN_2_CRMname);
    $('#GEN_2_D').val(item.get_fieldValues().GEN_2_CRMname_D);
}, function (sender, args) { alert('Error:' + args.get_message()); });

)};
```