# get_fieldValues of radio button javascript?

Tags: list, javascript, sharepoint-online, item

I need to get fieldValues of radio buttons i have successful got it from textareas and from dropdown

To get it for textareas and dropdown i used this way:

```
$('#GEN_1').val(item.get_fieldValues().GEN_1_Sum_Scope_Assigment);
```

and i tried to get it from radio button this way:

```
$('input[name="GEN20"]:checked').val(item.get_fieldValues().GEN_20_EL);
$('#GEN_20 input[name="GEN20"]').val(item.get_fieldValues().GEN_20_EL);  
$('#GEN_20 input[name="GEN20"]:checked').val(item.get_fieldValues().GEN_20_EL);
```

HTML for radio button

```
<input id="GEN_20_1" type="radio" name="GEN20" value="1">Ja
<br />
<input id="GEN_20_2" type="radio" name="GEN20" value="0">Nej
```

How can i do it?

My other question to know more what I'm doing:

[Load list item to dispaly get_fieldValues?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/119403/load-list-item-to-dispaly-get-fieldvalues/119442#119442)

**Update**

I want it to set the "black dot" in the one that is checked when i get the value

[image]

Comment: Can you update your question with HTML code of Radio Buttons

Comment: I have updated it now

Comment: I have updated my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below

```
$("input[name=GEN20][value=" + item.get_fieldValues().GEN_20_EL == false ? 0 : 1 + "]").attr('checked', 'checked');

//OR

$("input[name=GEN20][value=" + item.get_fieldValues().GEN_20_EL == false ? 0 : 1 + "]").prop('checked', 'checked');
```

Another option

```
if(item.get_fieldValues().GEN_20_EL == true) {
    $('#GEN_20_1').attr('checked','checked');
}
else
    $('#GEN_20_2').attr('checked','checked');
```

Comment: Tested but neiter worked going to update mu question to let you know more what i want

Comment: Put an alert statement to display what value comes for `item.get_fieldValues().GEN_20_EL`

Comment: i get false and it is set to false(No) but why will it not show "the black dot"?

Comment: Because the radio button value is "1" and "0". Hence setting its not working. I have updated my code to handle that

Comment: i haven't tried your new answers but just letting you know that i still got false but it set to yes going to try your new way know